# How do I rotate libstreaming Video Preview?

Tags: android, video, orientation, surfaceview

I am a noob to android development and I am trying to implement the [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) [example 3 sample project](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming-examples/tree/master/example3).  Everything works fine except that I haven't been able to change the orientation of the the video preview to prtrait.  No matter what settings I change it refuses to rotate and stays in landscape mode.  I know that it is possible to achieve portrait orientation because [spydroid](https://github.com/fyhertz/spydroid-ipcamera) uses libstreaming and displays in portrait orientation  Any help is greatly appreciated.

My relevant code:

```
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); //<--Does Nothing

    // Configures the SessionBuilder
    mSession = SessionBuilder.getInstance()
            .setContext(getApplicationContext())
            .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_AAC)
            .setAudioQuality(new AudioQuality(8000, 16000))
            .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264)
            .setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView)
            .setPreviewOrientation(90) //<--Does Nothing
            .setCallback(this)
            .build();
```

Comment: Have you try to change the orientation through the manifest?

Comment: Yes i have, but that idn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example 3 code, it seems the orientation is fixed in the manifest..just leave it out empty (do not even set to portrait)

```
        <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:name="net.majorkernelpanic.example3.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">
```

This will allow your activity to change orientation.

To force the orientation, add the below lines at the end of `onCreate` (after `selectQuality();` line)

```
    mSession.setPreviewOrientation(90);
    mSession.configure();
```

Comment: I've been struggling with this same problem as well.  Unfortunately, when I tried this solution it still displayed in landscape.  Setting orientation as portrait in manifest didn't work either.

Comment: @DollaBill I tried the example 3 on emulator, and when i rotated the emulator to portrait, the preview changed to portrait (with above changes).

Comment: When I run example on a device, it responds to configuration/orientation changes.  But displays the preview as landscape when the device is held portrait and displays the preview as upside-down landscape when the device is held landscape.

Comment: I get the same behavior as DollaBill is describing.

Comment: @B.Money you can force the orientation , please see my update to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Explore "libstreaming" library then go to:

1. VideoStream.java class
2. Find createCamera() method, replace "mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(mOrientation);"
   with mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
3. Find updateCamera(),  replace "mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(mOrientation);"
   with "mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);"